# Spring - avoiding ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: xml, spring, applicationcontext

Is it possible to get beans other than through the standard:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    Foo foo = context.getBean(Foo.class);
```

?

Using annotations for example.

Comment: It would be useful to see some context/use case.